# Returning 2 columns from the same field? [Oracle]

Tags: mysql, oracle, return

I've a Databases exam coming up so I'm doing a past paper on the subject. The language we are using is Oracle. I'm considering this study so please don't think I'm asking for homework answers. I've been trying to get my head around this for a while.

The case study is a city bike rental scheme. Here is the database the question is based on:

[image: scrshot]

The question states: Write an SQL statement to return all possible pairs of station locations (station.locatn) a cyclist might use - eg. "Bolton Street", "Charlemont Place". Your results should only show each pair once ie. "Bolton Street", "Charlemont Place" should not appear in the same result set.

So from this I gather that I have to return 2 columns where each row consists of 2 locations from the station.loctn field and each pair may only appear once. How do I return 2 columns of the same field?

Comment: You can include the same field name in the result set but alias them to give them a unique name. Likely in this situation you would be joining to the table twice (self join) and aliasing the same column on each join

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4604a8/2 heres a fiddle to get you going, you need to figure out how to eliminate duplicates

Comment: Thanks very much the code you gave in the fiddle was very useful!

Comment: @Charleh: the Fiddle above doesn't work for you. If it doesn't work for you as well, would you be able to recover it in some way and add it as an answer?

Comment: @halfer yeah in hindsight this was supposed to be a throwaway comment and I was expecting the OP to answer their own question. :( if I get time I'll come back and answer, but at the moment I'm on my mobile!